# How to get the elements <and> and <or> in XPath with Jre default Processor (JAXPSAXProcessor)

Tags: java, xpath, xslt, jaxp

I am working with some xml files which contain and/or tags. I want to transform them to 
html. In my XSL I am using two templates

```
<xsl:template match="and">
    (
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[1]" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[2]" />
    )
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="or">
    (
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[1]" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[2]" />
    )
</xsl:template>
```

It Works when i am using Xalan as a processor but when I am using JAXPSAXProcessor I am getting errors: 
 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Syntax error in 'or'.
ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Syntax error in 'and'.

I suppose that JaxPSaxProcessor translates and/or to the operators in Xpath. 
[here you can see the list of operators](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp) 
I can not change the jaxb processor because it have been used in many places. Is there any other sugesstion to  solve the problem?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for some techniques you may try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the XSLT processor is *that* buggy, you may try cheating it using a number of techniques**, such as:

```
<xsl:template match="*[name()=concat('a', 'nd')">
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="*[name()=substring('land',2)">
```

Good luck.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I think that even `*[name()='and']` should avoid conflics in buggy XPath parser.

Comment: @Govan: Glad this was useful. Then you can consider accepting and upvoting the answer. :)